# How to insert a value in double pointer (2D array) in a specific location

Tags: c

```
int **p = NULL;

p = (int **) malloc(sizeof (int *) * 3);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    p[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof (int) * 4);
```

In this code a double pointer is used as 2D array. My questions are

1. if i want to insert 1 at every position.
2. if i want to insert value 2 at specific location

How can i do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to index an array?

Comment: If you use the allocated space as a 2D array, does that not imply that you will access elements via the indexing operator (`[]`)?  In pairs, since it's 2D?

Comment: @EugeneSh i mean if i allocated double pointer then how can i put values in it and insert a value at a specific location

Comment: With `p[x][y]`.. ?

Comment: I should probably mention that [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/8420233).

Comment: Or, with `*(*(p + x) + y)` which is the same as `*(p[x] + y)` which is the same as `p[x][y]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using index operator as 2D array.

**if you want to insert 1 at every position.**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        p[i][j] = 1;
}
```

**if you want to insert value 2 at specific location at row i, column j**

```
p[i][j] = 2;
```